# controller arguments should change text

Tags: angularjs

$scope.man="A"; //default text

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <p>person clicked {{man}}</p>
        <button ng-click="man('b')">B</button><br>
        <button ng-click="man('c')">C</button>
    </div>
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
        $scope.man="A";
    $scope.man=function(value)
    {
        $scope.man=value;
    }
});
```

i am new to angularjs i wanted to change text by arguments but text is not changing and the default text A is also not getting displayed can some one help me out with this

check this link
https://jsfiddle.net/nikhila/31gz56tn/

Answer (score 0):

Your $scope variable and function are same. Change your function like this,

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <p>person clicked {{man}}</p>
        <button ng-click="change('b')">B</button><br>
        <button ng-click="change('c')">C</button>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.man = "A";
  $scope.change = function(value) {
    $scope.man = value;
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/fkq92kha/)**

Comment: and call as: <button ng-click="change('b')">